# Ctrl+V and Powerpoint 2010

Tags: autohotkey

The "Find" dialog in PowerPoint 2010 does not behave as expected.  Pressing Ctrl+F will bring up the dialog and the last search term, but it will not be highlighted.  The cursor will be at the beginning of the search term, so if I press Ctrl+F and just start typing, I'll essentially be prepending my new search term onto the one I searched for last.  To avoid this, I have to manually delete the contents of the search box before I type what I want to search.  Super annoying.

Enter AHK.  I have this as my script:

```
loop {
    WinWait, ahk_class NUIDialog ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
    Sleep, 50
    Send ^a
    WinWaitClose
}
```

What this does is it waits for the Powerpoint Find dialog to appear, then it "presses" Ctrl+A for me so it highlights previous search term so I can just start typing.  But here is where the problem arises, and I can't figure out how to get around it.

When I press Ctrl+F, the script works fine.  And if I then press Ctrl+V, I can paste text into the box (as expected). But, if I instead keep Ctrl pressed after pressing Ctrl+F, then press V (Ctrl+F, then V, then release Ctrl), I just get the letter "v".  It seems like AHK releases the Ctrl key after it sends Ctrl+A, when though I still have Ctrl still pressed.  How can I avoid this behavior?  How can I prevent AHK from releasing the Ctrl key if I still have the Ctrl key pressed (if that's what's even happening)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [blind mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind) to not release the modifier.
And I would also recommend [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) even though it's not going to make any meaningful difference with this script. It's faster and more reliable and generally the preferred send mode, so yeah.

```
SendInput, {Blind}^a
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that did the trick!  I don't think I ever would have known to look for that.